# ConnectApi.NotFoundException: Resource not found (ConnectApi.Communities)

Tags: connect-api

I'm trying to get the community site url, using the ConnectApi in a lightning component, with a SystemAdmin it works fine, but not with any other profile.

Here is my code

```
final Network myNetwork = [SELECT Id FROM Network WHERE Name ='NET NAME'];
final ConnectApi.Community  myCommunity = ConnectApi.Communities.getCommunity(myNetwork.Id);
```

The other profile has access to:

- Apex REST Services
- API Enabled

Do I need to add another permission?ßß

Comment: is apex class sharing or without sharing?

Comment: without sharing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From docs mentioned [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000192853&type=1) :

> You will only get Ids of the Communities the running user has access
>   to.

You have to Give that profile access to that community. In other words, you have to make that user member of that community to allow him to post.

You can add that profile in the community by going to

**Setup -> Communities -> You Community -> WorkSpaces -> Adminsitation -> Member and chose the selected profile.**

Comment: It works now. Many thanks!